# Hide the second testimonial from owl-carousel in screen sizes lower than 1200px

Tags: html, css

I'm using a carousel that allows me to set 2 testimonials to appear at a single set (2 testimonials per slide) and I've configurated it to show 2 testimonials when teh screen size at lease 1200px, so when the screen size get lower than 1200px it automatically should reduce to a single testimonial. But because of a CSS problem the second slide is still appearing in lower screens. I've tried the following code in my css to fix it, with no success:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
.owl-wrapper > li:nth-child(2) {display: none !important;}
}
```

Does anyone has an idea in how to fix this? site: http://rache.me/testsite

Comment: it should be min-width instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the child combinator, so this would only target li elements that are the direct children of .owl-wrapper.  Try the same code on the divs instead.

```
.owl-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {display: none;}
```